# libgdx - render() with a little "breaks"

Tags: libgdx

I've started to programming with Libgdx just today, and i want to move my camera infinitely down, dynamically rendering my background, so camera always have something to see.

The thing is, I made a code that does that, but I'm noticing some "breaks" in the passage of background. It is not smooth enough, and i can't figure it out why.. To see better these "breaks" just raise the property "speed".

I've hosted my project and the link is below. If someone can analyse the code, I'll be glad!

Thanks a lot!

Project: [http://www.4shared.com/rar/SEjnsbLsce/drop_*1*.html](http://www.4shared.com/rar/SEjnsbLsce/drop__1_.html)

EDIT:

The "breaks" is like a 0.1 pause on the camera movement. Is not smooth enough, sometimes im having this little pauses.

I already tried to do manually, to see if the "breaks" continues, and it is continue.

render():

```
batch.draw(backgroundImage, backgroundSprite.getX(), 0);
batch.draw(backgroundImage, backgroundSprite.getX(), -800 );
batch.draw(backgroundImage, backgroundSprite.getX(), -1600 );
.
.
.
batch.draw(backgroundImage, backgroundSprite.getX(), -9600 );
```

I made my dynamic code really fast, i know i can do a lot better then this, but i'm programming to make it works, then, refactor:

render():

```
camera.position.set(camera.position.x, camera.position.y - (speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()), camera.position.z);

batch.begin();

if( yWalked < backgroundSprite.getHeight() * backgroundCounter ){
    batch.draw(backgroundImage, backgroundSprite.getX(), ( ( backgroundSprite.getHeight() * backgroundCounter ) - backgroundSprite.getHeight()) * -1);
}

if( ( yWalked + backgroundSprite.getHeight() ) > ( backgroundSprite.getHeight() * backgroundCounter ) ){        
    batch.draw(backgroundImage, backgroundSprite.getX(), (backgroundSprite.getHeight() * backgroundCounter) * -1 );            
}

if( yWalked > backgroundSprite.getHeight() * backgroundCounter ){
    backgroundCounter++;
}

yWalked = yWalked + ( speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() );

batch.end();
```

Comment: You're going to get better help faster if you post some example code here directly instead of making us download another file. What do these breaks look like? What code do you believe is causing them?

Comment: I see.. it's because i really dont know what is causing it that i hosted the entire project. I will add some code in a minute.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok, if you think i need to add some other snippet, please, let me know!

Comment: Have you tryed displaying the FPS count somewhere? Maybe this "break" occures sometimes cause FPS go down for some reason

Comment: The garbage collector can cause little occasional stutters. Make sure you aren't allocating many objects on each render loop.

Comment: Instead of drawing your background multiple times in multiple places, I'd recommend using UV coordinates and make the texture repeatable.  I have an example here in a project of mine that allows for entities in a CES to have automated scrolling textures

http://bit.ly/1bm4YAb

Comment: Look this: http://imgur.com/7xnwXq9

The only code i have in my project is fpsLogger = new FPSLogger(); When the fps goes lower then 66, i can see the "break". Sometimes the fps goes to 64, 62.. and i dont have nothing in my code...

I assume that i can't avoid this "lower then 66 fps", am i right?

Comment: You should take a look at 'Background Scrolling', you are displaying hundreds time your background at differents positions, even when the background is not displayed, you render, that may cause the breaks. You should only use two backgrounds with the scrolling way